# converting elements of a list to string

Tags: java, string, list, collections

I would like to obtain the string text of the elements stored in a list, say `List<Car>`. Would the toArray() and the toString() methods be the best options?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, but doing it manually gives you more control:

```
// initialize with the exact length
List<String> stringsList = new ArrayList<String>(listOfCars.size()); 
for (Car car : listOfCars) {
    stringsList.add(car.toString());   
}
```

If you haven't overridden the `toString()` method or don't want to override it, you can use `car.getName()` instead of `car.toString()` (or any property combination you like)

Answer (score 20):

Another idea is to use the [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) to write the following code:

```
StringUtils.join(myList);
```

The interest is that you also can provide a separator, for example:

```
StringUtils.join(myList, " ; ");
```

Answer (score 13):

Providing you don't object to the string output following the convention:

```
[A, B, C]
```

... you can simply call the `List`'s`toString()` method to obtain your output (I'm not sure why people are advocating using a loop for this).  It may also be sensible to override Car's `toString()` method to return a human-friendly description of the object.

However, if you wish to obtain each element as an individual `String` you will need to iterate over the List one element at a time.

Comment: How can you be sure the output will look like this? List is just an interface and there is no contract about the output of the toString() method in List.

Comment: @Dominik: It's a fair point but I would guess that in 99.9% of cases people tend to use the JDK implementations of List, which do produce this style of output.  I tend to use this output for debug logging  but would never rely on it for presentation-level logic.

Comment: This is the right approach imho as it comes from [AbstractCollection#toString](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toString()) which implementations should extend from and collection types within the JDK do so.

Answer (score 8):

There is a `static toString(Object[])` method an `java.util.Arrays`. Calling it with the `toArray()` result of the List (as you suggested) should do the job.

Comment: Why not just call toString() on the list directly?

Comment: @Adamski: The interface List does not define a contract for toString().

Comment: There is also `deepToString()` if needed

Answer (score 5):

You can use Java 8 `Streams`

```
List<Car> carList = new ArrayList<>();
//Add some elemts to carList
carList.stream()
.map(Car::toString) // maps Car Object to a value returned by toString method
.collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

Refer [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html) about `Collectors` for more info.

Comment: I've posted a few extra examples of Collectors.joining() in a separate answer. It was a bit much for an edit! Feel free to copy my answer into yours so it's in one place, if you like. I will then delete my answer.

Answer (score 3):

First convert your List (Collection) to an array, and create a string of each element.

```
Arrays.toString(myCollection.toArray());
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't want to give a separate answer from hkbharath, which is a good answer, but I do want to give more examples of using Java 8 streams. The Collectors.joining() has a few different overloaded variants.

Let's say that the code in his example:

```
carList.stream()
.map(Car::toString) // maps Car Object to a value returned by toString method
.collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

Gives you this: Ford,Honda,Buick

Then if you don't need a delimiter:

```
carList.stream()
.map(Car::toString) // maps Car Object to a value returned by toString method
.collect(Collectors.joining());
```

Would give you instead: FordHondaBuick

And here is an extended example showing how to manipulate each string, change the delimiter, and add a prefix and suffix:

```
carList.stream()
.map(Car::toString) // maps Car Object to a value returned by toString method
.map(String::toUpperCase) // Transform to upper case
.collect(Collectors.joining("; ", "[", "]"));
```

Would give you instead: [FORD; HONDA; BUICK]

Answer (score -4):

```
for (Car car : carsList) {  // carsList is the object of List<Car>
    System.out.println(car);
}
```

Note: The above will display the meaningful message only when you have overridden the toString() method of Car class.

e.g

```
public class Car {

    private String carName;

    ....
    ....

    public String toString() {
        return carName;
    }
}
```

The toString() method should be overridden to return meaningful information about the object in the string form.

In your case, I think the meaningful info would be all the details of the car. So overriding toString() method is best approach instead of using getCarName() or similar methods.